# Question about row operations not changing linear independence of columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two row equivalent matrices $A$ and $B$ where
\begin{align}
A & = \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_n \end{array}\right] \\B & = \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} c'_1 & c'_2 & \cdots & c'_n \end{array}\right].\end{align} And I make some vector $d = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 &\cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix}$. Then we assume $A d = 0$ (Which there will be always at least the solution where $d$ is just the zero vector so it's not really just an assumption but okay). Then turns out that $B d = 0$ also holds and so $a_1 c_1 + a_2c_2  + \dots = 0$ and $a_1 c_1' + a_2c_2' + \dots = 0$ both hold. How does this really tell me that the linear relations hold between both columns?

Comment: Gather the $a_i$ terms.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This would only be true when $n > {\rm rows}(A)$

Answer (score 1):

Saying there is a linear relation between the columns of a matrix$~M$ means precisely there is a nonzero column vector $v$ of the proper size such that $Mv$ is a zero vector (in the space of column vectors of the size of the columns of$~M$). This is because such $Mv$ *is* a linear combination of the columns of $M$, with coefficients given by the entries of $v$. And every linear non-trivial combination of the columns of $M$ is so obtained for some $v$ (excluding the trivial combination is because $v=0$ is excluded).

So when for any $d$ one has $Ad=0$ if and only $Bd=0$ (it appears that you already proved $Ad=0\implies Bd=0$ and the opposite implication follows by symmetry between $A$ and $B$), then there is a non-trivial relation between the columns of $A$ if and only if there is a non-trivial relation (with the very same sequence of coefficients) between the columns of $B$, which appears to be what you wanted to prove.